# Is there a way to know how many people clicked my link?

Tags: discussion, badges, hyperlinks

I know I can share Q&A with this kind of links:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/typeOfPost/#postId/#myUserId
```

I also know that I can earn [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer) with this.

But is there a way to know how many clicks a [link with tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29141619/2307070) actually got?

---

I understand that the data is not available on the Stack Overflow site, but is there a way to access with through it via [Data SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries)? I mean, this data *is* stored somewhere isn't they?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67240/248731

Comment: No. Not until you get a badge for it.

See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67240/view-progress-towards-announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges on MSE.

Comment: @Scimonster this is the same link than jonrsharpe but untracked ;)

Comment: Hmm, i had posted that as an answer but it got converted to a comment.

Comment: I've no idea why three community members decided to delete the answer suggesting a bit.ly link. If someone want to share a link to a stackoverflow post on a non StackExchange site (which is what the badges incentivise) it's totally their call if they want to use a link shortener,

Comment: Because a bit.ly link can links to *anything* which is quite bad in term of security... @MartinSmith

Comment: So are you suggesting all posts mentioning link shorteners should be removed by the community on grounds of security? bit.ly does provide a mechanism to preview by appending a `+` for the paranoid. If you're sharing links successfully it is presumably with people who already follow you on twitter, read your blog etc and who have some expectation that the link will be worth following.

Comment: I didn't say that I approve what's done here. I said why it happens

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only way you can find out how many clicks a link got is when you get one of the sharing badges for that link.

You will be told the link that the badge was awarded for, but that's all the information you get.

Comment: And the datas aren't accessible via DataSE ?

Comment: @Thomas - not as far as I know, and if they were I'm sure someone would have posted such an answer by now.