# Allow users to track site promotion badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-progress

Is it possible to let users to track their progress for site promotion badges such as **Announcer**, **Booster** and **Publicist**?

There's no way to track the progress now, it would good if users can track the progress using a SEDE query or in the site itself.

---

It it quite troublesome to use external analytics as sometimes they are not accurate. I've shared [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/5022249) but didn't manage to get the badge even though it has been visited around 30 times according to analytics.

However, this may be due to the same user opening the links a few times, making the analytics inaccurate.

---

**Update:**

I understand that similar questions had been asked before as stated in the comments, however, there's still isn't a reliable solution to this yet.

Methods such as using an external analytics to track link clicks is not feasible as explained earlier.

Comment: This has been asked before on [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67240/view-progress-towards-announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges).

Comment: @Glorfindel True, but nothing was introduced to address this

Comment: [Is there a way to know how many people clicked my link?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291785/is-there-a-way-to-know-how-many-people-clicked-my-link)

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, but it doesn't really solve this problem

Comment: @luweiqi if you are looking for solutions/attention for an existing problem, put a bounty on it rather than duplicating it.

Comment: @TJ You know that you can't do bounties on MSO, right? (Only MSE.)

Comment: @Laurel Yep,  I know. Same request exists in MSE regarding same badges...